# Append elements in list

Tags: python, list, element

I am new to Python and have a question about list.

Can i append the elements in a list to add text in front and after ?

**Example**

```
mylist = ['Audi', 'Bmw', 'Mercedes']
```

I want to add " sign to every other item so it looks like this:

```
mylist = ['"Audi"', '"Bmw"', '"Mercedes"']
```

Comment: May I ask why?  This appears to add a complexity to the strings which will/might need to be undone later.

Comment: [f'"{item}"' for item in mylist]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try list comprehension:

```
mylist = ['"'+x+'"' for x in mylist]
```

Format stringed version:

```
mylist = ['"{}"'.format(x) for x in mylist]
```

F-stringed (Python 3.6+)

```
mylist = [f'"{x}"' for x in mylist]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the list then append each element in your list to a new list with inverted commas.

```
my_list = ['Audi','Bmw','Mercedes']
a = []
for i in my_list:
    a.append("\""+i+"\"")
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python strings can never be changed, so you always have to create a new one if you want to modify something. There are very many ways to create new strings using data from existing strings. Here are just a few:

Strings can be "added" together (concatenated) using the plus operator:

```
>>> 'hello' + ' ' + 'world!'
'hello world'
```

Strings can be built using a C (the programming language) style template:

```
>>> 'hello %s!' % 'world'
'hello world!
```

Python also has its own template [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) which must be used with the `format` method:

```
>>>'{} {}!'.format('hello', 'world')
'hello world!'
```

now that you know how to modify the strings, you simply need to find a way to do it to each string in your list.

A very simple, but verbose way might be to iterate over a list index, and modify the existing elements of the list in-place (lists are mutable, so each item can be changed without creating a new list):

```
>>> for i in range(len(mylist)):
>>>    mylist[i] = '"{}"'.format(mylist[i])
```

Alternately, python has a convenient form for creating new lists from an existing iterable object called a [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) (because it's a very common thing to do).

```
>>> new_list = ['"{}"'.format(item) for item in mylist]
```